# How to wrap or justicy the contents of PrimeNg's p-timeline

Tags: angular, primeng

I don't know whether wrap is the correct term or justify. I'm using PrimeNg's `p-timeline`. I'm doing exactly as mentioned in the official documentation:

```
<p-timeline [value]="events" layout="horizontal">
    <ng-template pTemplate="content" let-event>
        {{event.status}}
    </ng-template>
</p-timeline>

----------------------------------
events: any[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.events = [
    {status: 'Processing complete', ...},
    {status: 'Processing complete', ...},
    {status: 'Processing complete', ...},
    {status: 'Processing complete', ...}
  ];
```

I'm displaying the same inside an accordion. On the UI it looks like this:
[image]

Notice the last event. It is always in two lines. Even if I increase or decrease number of events the last one is always like that:
[image]

This is my CSS:

```
.custom-marker {
    display: flex;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
```

Is this a known issue? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a known issue?

Yes, PrimeNG is a known issue.

Jokes aside, unfortunately it's a [known but ignored](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/10129) bug of PrimeNG.

There's a workaround you might find enough for your case:

```html
<div class="card">
  <p-timeline [value]="events" layout="horizontal">
    <ng-template pTemplate="marker" let-event>
      <span class="custom-marker p-shadow-2" [style.backgroundColor]="event.color">
        <i [ngClass]="event.icon"></i>
      </span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="content" let-event>
      <span class="status" [attr.data-status]="event.status">{{ event.status }}</span>
    </ng-template>
  </p-timeline>
</div>
```

```scss
:host ::ng-deep {
  .custom-marker {
    display: flex;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }

  .p-timeline-horizontal {
    .p-timeline-event:last-child {
      .p-timeline-event-content {
        position: relative;

        .status {
          $bigValue: 999999px;

          display: block;
          overflow: hidden;
          text-indent: -$bigValue;

          &::after {
            content: attr(data-status);
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            padding: 1rem 0;
            text-indent: $bigValue;
            white-space: nowrap;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The downside of this approach is that the last point can now overlap the others on small screens but maybe you can live with that.

See it live on [Stackblitz](https://primeng-timeline-demo-etrumv.stackblitz.io) or check the [source](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-timeline-demo-etrumv?file=src/app/app.component.scss).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Its working also. But ive lost my `.custom-marker`. I still need it. It is mentioned i the primeng doc also. I need to show some clock icons as well as mentioned in my screenshot

Comment: The `.custom-marker` icon still can be easily applied on top of that as demonstrated by the updated stackblitz.

Comment: Accepting the answer as it solved my problem. But please let me know if you know the solution for this overlapping of last point also. I'll wait for the answer.

Comment: Can you pitch in here please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73178335/how-to-chnage-the-style-of-p-calnder-input-field-border